# Is there anyway i can rescale kinect depth image format resolution?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

The current depth image format resolution is --> Depth Image Format.Resolution 640x480 Fps 30

I wonder if it can be changed instead of the fixed 640x480, 320x240, 160x120.

How can i create the boundaries to detect skeletons from exiting the set boundary.

The original:

```
if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
{
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
}
```

Editted code:

```
Rect myRect1 = new Rect(160, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight);

RectangleGeometry myRectangleGeometry1 = new RectangleGeometry();
myRectangleGeometry1.Rect = myRect1;

if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(myRect1.Bottom))
{
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red,null,new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
}
```

In my edited code "Bottom" doesnt work for myRect1 that i created, that part doesnt work, can someone enlighten me on how i should be doing it.

So far frame edges is controlled by depth image resolution (640x480).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you actually want to collect data at that size, or just display it at that size?  In the case of former - that decreases your sensitivity, which would not generally benefit you.  In the case of the latter - you just need to put the output into a XAML object that is scaled to the appropriate size.

Comment: thanks for enlightening me. Im thinking of setting boundaries for tracked skeleton, if it leaves that boundary my media player will be activated to alert me

Comment: In that case you are not looking to change resolution.  You need to check the x/y/z of the active skeleton -- when one or more of those values go out of range from defined constants you can fire your alert.

Comment: The original:

if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

Comment: Editted code:

Rect myRect1 = new Rect(160, 0.0, RenderWidth, RenderHeight);
           
            RectangleGeometry myRectangleGeometry1 = new RectangleGeometry();
            myRectangleGeometry1.Rect = myRect1;

if (skeleton.ClippedEdges.HasFlag(myRect1.Bottom))
            {
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
                    Brushes.Red,
                    null,
                    new Rect(0, RenderHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, RenderWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
            }

Comment: some how myRect1.Bottom doesnt work. Im trying to create a rectangle so that when the skeleton leaves the rectangle by the left or right it will fire off the alert. Im not very well versed in programming. Thanks for ur patience and time

Comment: Please edit your question.  You can update the title and text of your original question and also include the above code so that it is more readable.

Comment: Okay done. Im not sure if the way i create the rectangle is correct.